# how to search a string from one file and update to another in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

I have two files I am searching strings one by one from one file and updating the record into another file. Say i have text file A.csv

```
TABLE1, ABC_STRING
TABLE2, ABC_STRING
TABLE3, ABC_STRING
```

B.csv

```
TABLEA,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLEB,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLE1,SOMEVALUE,ABC_INT,NULL,ABC_INT
TABLEC,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLE2,SOMEVALUE,ABC_INT,NULL,ABC_INT
TABLE3,SOMEVALUE,ABC_INT,NULL,ABC_INT
```

Expecting the output in a new file like:

```
TABLEA,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLEB,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLE1,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLEC,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLE2,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLE3,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
```

I tried like this:

```
for i in $(grep -w "ABC_STRING" A.csv | awk -F ',' '{print $1}'); do
grep -w "$i" B.csv | sed 's/ABC_INT/ABC_STRING/g'
done | more
```

I am not sure how to write the command to copy each and every line check whether it contains the string if it is available replace and write it in C.csv if not write it into the same C.csv. Could anyone please provide a code snippet for my requirement.

Comment: Is `"ABC_STRING"` really the same on all those lines, and `"ABC_INT"` is fixed as well?

Comment: Why are you doing `grep -w "ABC_STRING" A.csv` when in your sample input **every** line of A.csv contains `ABC_STRING` - is that not the case in your real input? If so then update your example to be more truly representative of your real data.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F', *' -v OFS=',' 'NR==FNR{m[$1]=$2; next} $1 in m{$3=$5=m[$1]} 1' A.csv B.csv > C.csv
```

Comment: some explanation of the AWK script would be nice

Comment: @Bodo but completely unnecessary and counter-productive for anyone wanting to learn awk who could benefit far more from a glance at the man pages than being spoon-fed this particular application of the constructs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Perl

```
perl -pe ' 
         BEGIN { %kv=map{chomp;split(",")} qx(cat A.csv) }  
         /^(.+?),/ and $kv{$1} and s/ABC_INT/ABC_STRING/g 
'
```

using the given inputs

```
$  perl -pe ' BEGIN {%kv=map{chomp;split(",")} qx(cat A.csv)}  /^(.+?),/ and $kv{$1} and s/ABC_INT/ABC_STRING/g ' B.csv
TABLEA,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLEB,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLE1,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLEC,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLE2,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLE3,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING

$
```

Answer (score 0):

Because unix

```
cat <<EOF >A.csv
TABLE1, ABC_STRING
TABLE2, ABC_STRING
TABLE3, ABC_STRING
EOF

cat <<EOF >B.csv
TABLEA,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLEB,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLE1,SOMEVALUE,ABC_INT,NULL,ABC_INT
TABLEC,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
TABLE2,SOMEVALUE,ABC_INT,NULL,ABC_INT
TABLE3,SOMEVALUE,ABC_INT,NULL,ABC_INT
EOF


# join the first file on the first field
# with the second file on the second field
# print unmatched lines from the second file
# the unknown matches are substituted with ##
# the output is complicated - we output the matched correct line (6 fields)
# and after it we output the original second file (6 fields)
# when there is no match, the last field from the correct line 
# is the empty separator '##' 
# we can filter is later with sed
join -11 -22 -t, -a2 -e'##' -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,1.2,2.5,1.2,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6 <(
    # dunno what the spaces are doing in A.csv, remove them
    <A.csv tr -d ' ' | 
    # sort the file on the first field
    sort -k1 -t,
) <(
    # add a number of the lines to the second file
    # so we can sort it like the original file later
    <B.csv nl -s, -w1 | 
    # sort it on the second field (the first field is the number now)
    sort -k2 -t,
) |
# here the output looks like: 
# 6,TABLE3,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING,6,TABLE3,SOMEVALUE,ABC_INT,NULL,ABC_INT
# 1,TABLEA,SOMEVALUE,##,NULL,##,1,TABLEA,SOMEVALUE,ABC_STRING,NULL,ABC_STRING
# remove the first 6 fields from the lines with `##,` they were not matched
sed 's/.*,##,//' |
# extract first 6 fields, less to sort, operation is cheap
cut -d, -f1-6 |
# sort on the field numerical. This is the numbers we inserted in the second file
sort -k1 -t, -n |
# extract 5 lines from the original
cut -d, -f2-6
```